# Trimming characters with SqlFunctions in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, t-sql

This is my code:

```
(from customer in db.tblCustomers
  join product in db.tblProducts on customer.product_id equals product.id into str
  from prod in str.DefaultIfEmpty()
  where customer.code.Substring(SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%[^0]%", customer.code).Value - 1) == customerCode
  select prod.name).SingleOrDefault();
```

As you can see, I use PatIndex for left trimming the string, but I also want to right trim the zeroes. How can I do that?

For example, if customerCode is '123', and in db if I have a customer code with value '001230000', it is a match.

Comment: reverse string, and then same code.

Answer (score 0):

Validate the characters after `CustomerCode` are all zeroes:

```
(from customer in db.tblCustomers
  join product in db.tblProducts on customer.product_id equals product.id into str
  from prod in str.DefaultIfEmpty()
  let tail = customer.code.Substring(customer.code.IndexOf(customerCode)+customerCode.Length)
  where customer.code.Substring(SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%[^0]%", customer.code).Value - 1) == customerCode &&
        tail == new String('0', tail.Length)
  select prod.name).SingleOrDefault();
```